# stripe api not picking my live key in settings

Tags: python, django, heroku, stripe-payments

I have set up a model in django code is:

```
import stripe

from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.db import models
stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY

#Stripe
class UserStripe(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    stripe_id = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.stripe_id)


def get_or_create_stripe(sender, user, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        user.userstripe.stripe_id
    except UserStripe.DoesNotExist:
        customer = stripe.Customer.create(
            email = str(user.email)
        )
        new_user_stripe = UserStripe.objects.create(
                user=user,
                stripe_id = customer.id,
                )
    except:
        pass

user_logged_in.connect(get_or_create_stripe)
```

I have changed my api key to the live code in settings and even deleted the old test api key in stripe. But the app is still using the old api and i am getting the following error all the time.

> AuthenticationError at /accounts/login/ Expired API Key provided:
>   sk_test_********************IddZ Request Method:  Django Version: 1.8.4
>   Exception Type:   AuthenticationError Exception Value:     Expired API Key
>   provided: sk_test_********************IddZ Exception
>   Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stripe/api_requestor.py
>   in handle_api_error, line 163 Python
>   Executable:   /app/.heroku/python/bin/python Python Version:  2.7.12
>   Python Path:   ['/app',  '/app/.heroku/python/bin',  '/app', 
>   '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python27.zip', 
>   '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7', 
>   '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', 
>   '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
>   '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-old', 
>   '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', 
>   '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages', 
>   '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-25.2.0-py2.7.egg',
>   '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg']
>   Server time:  Sun, 13 Nov 2016 17:25:32 +0000

Any ideas:

Comment: Did you try resetting your server, and are you using the correct settings file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is correct and api are correct, after I run `heroku restart` to reboot the dyno, it worked.